# Merging header file and cpp file

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm working on a C++ project where I've implemented every class as a separate .h file and .cpp file. I'm finding out this wasn't worth the hassle. 
 - I'm editing back and forth between two files
 - It caused me a lot of unsuspected headaches (having to add predeclaration, explicitly export templated classes)
 - I don't see a direct benefit, my code base is bound to stay relatively small (say < 10,000 lines of code) and compilation time isn't substantial.

My question is two fold

a) Is there a benefit I might have missed in keeping implementation and prototype separated?

b) If not, is there any free tool or ide that has the capability of merging a cpp file back into the header file?

Comment: You might have missed the fact that clients can't view your implementation.

Comment: Presumably there was also hassle from having a class per cpp/hpp. Good practice in C++ allows grouping multiple related classes together in their own hpp/cpp pair.

Comment: If having multiple headers and code files is entirely too much trouble, you should probably just put all your code in a single file. After all, any editor these days will load 10kloc no problem. `/sarcasm` Even the temptation to do this is a fundamental misunderstanding of how the compilation process works.

Comment: Looking at the definition, or at least some breakdown, of *compilation units* and the stages of compilation (preprocessor, which will handle some of the includes, compiler, linker), will very quickly show why this is a Very Bad Idea. As Jonathon noted in his answer, `#include` literally includes *the text of the file* into the other file. If you're using MSVC, there is an option to retain the preprocessor outputs (`*.i`), which will shed even more light on this.

Comment: 1. cat *.h >> abc.cpp  2. cat *.cpp >> abc.cpp  3. g++ abc.cpp  :P

Comment: @chris I have no clients, this is entirely for my own use.

Answer (score 10):

Don't do this. For most simple classes, where you want to expose the class for use somewhere else, you should always* have the declaration of the class in a `.h` header file, and the definition (code) in a `.cpp` file.

You then include the `.h` file wherever you want to use the class (ie. instantiate it). However, the linker is responsible for "linking" the code up after each `.cpp` is compiled separately.

My question for you would be, "how else would you do it?" One mistake I see many n00bs make is to `#include "foo.c`. Then what happens is, not only do you lose the independent compilation, you run into problems at link-time because there are multiple definitions of the *same class*. Remember, when you `#include` a file, it literally plops in the body of that file where you say.

[*] There are of course exceptions to this rule:

One exception to this is for *template classes*. These have to be in a header file in their entirety. The reason is because the actual code is not generated until the class is instantiated with a type parameter. Then, the compiler essentially "fills-in" the body of the class with the specified type where required.  Since the type is not known until then, it *cannot* be compiled independently and linked-up later.

Comment: Sometimes you want classes that are only local to one cpp file. This can be for simplicity (no other file needs it) or in order to hide implementation/complexity. So you should not always have the declaration in the header file - only if you want to expose the class to use it elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexWilson Sometimes you need to have the declaration in the header even without intent to use it elsewhere; pimpl is an example of that case (and a common reason for class-within-cpp).

Comment: @peachykeen Absolutely. I agree entirely. I was just making the point that you should not always, without question, put your declaration in a header - which was how this post first read.

Comment: @AlexWilson And I would, in turn, agree with that. You should not *always* declare in the header.

Comment: @AlexWilson An I agree with both of you. However, I felt this was a newbie question, and I initially answered it in terms of dealing with simple, textbook classes. Of course there are exceptions, so I noted that as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for incorporating the suggestions too.

Comment: Many of my classes are templated. I use header guards, so classes would only be included once no matter what. (And I would NOT include a c or cpp file, the question here is about putting implementation inside the h file or not)

Comment: @ArthurB. Header guards **will not** help you here. Those only work per compilation unit (read: .cpp file). The next time the compiler starts up for a new .cpp file, it will *again* define that same class -- this time in a new object file. Then, when the linker goes to link them all together, it will have multiple definitions of the *same class name*.